# Document Store Data Modeling for Tree (data structure)

Tags: javascript, data-modeling

I'm Developing a bot, It has more Parent and Child `Button Keyboard` Menu, and i want to access to each Steps, Is my data model Good? and How Can I Improve That.
This is My Data Model:

```
{
    "Keyboard": {
        "StartKeyboard": [
            "Content",
            "Start",
            "About"
        ],
        "Start": {
            "parent": "StartKeyboard",
            "childs":[   
                "⚙️111⚙️",
                "222", 
                "333", 
                "4444", 
                "555"
            ]
        },
        "About": {
            "parent": "Start",
            "childs":[ 
                "111111111", 
                "2222222222", 
                "33333333333333", 
                "444444444",
                "55555555555"
            ]
        }
        "Content":{
            "message": "54645465468545485454654654654"
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Find a Good Data Model   `parent,child,left,right,path`

```
{
    "Keyboard": {
        "StartKeyboard": [
            "Content",
            "Start",
            "About"
        ],
        "Start": {
            "parent": "StartKeyboard",
            "childs":[   
                "4444", 
                "555"
            ]
            "left":
            "right":
            "path": Keyboard.StartKeyboard.Start
        }

    }
}
```